# Трава-мурава

Tags: этимология, лексика

Всегда было интересно, "трава-мурава" - это просто игра слов или "мурава" имеет какое-то значение?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Мурава** - "сочная луговая трава, дерн", укр. *мурава*, блр. *мурова*, др.-русск. *мурава*, болг. *мурава*, сербохорв. *мурава* "вид водоросли", словен. *murava* "мягкая трава, газон". От **мур**, родственного лит. mauras, мн. maurai~ "грязь, тина, зелень на поверхности стоячей воды", лтш. maurs "газон, мурава", mauragas ж. мн. "ястребинка" (далее связывается со словом **мох**).(источник - словарь Фасмера).